# Is it possible to add a property on a non-rooted android phone?

Tags: android, adb, seandroid

For my non-rooted device (which I am not allowed to root, so I need to find another way around), if I do

```
adb shell setprop MY_PROP 1
```

followed by

```
adb shell getprop MY_PROP
```

I get a blank line.

How can I set a property?

Comment: Ifound the same issue ... I think it is not possible ... even if you try > su cd /something you will get a white line ...

Answer (score 2):

By default the `shell` user is not allowed to create properties:

```
$ adb shell "setprop test.test 1; dmesg | grep test\.test"
[  271.706897,0] init: avc:  denied  { set } for property=test.test scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:default_prop:s0 tclass=property_service
[  271.707157,0] init: sys_prop: permission denied uid:2000  name:test.test
```

Answer (score 1):

Without root you can only add props that start with `debug.`

```
adb shell setprop debug.my.prop newProp
```